# Ionic unable to mute html5 video on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, video, ionic-framework

I am trying to mute a html5 video on Ionic 1.3 / iOS 10 but so far the video still play with volume equals to 1. This is my HTML

```
  <video muted="muted" preload="metadata" x-webkit-airplay="allow" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer" on-tap="onTap(1)">
      <source src="video/article1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
```

I understand the muted attribute doesn't work on iOS 10 what's why I used JS to set the volume to cero but still doesn't work on iOS thought it works in the browser

```
var video = $('.videoPlayer');
video.each(function(i){
    $(this).get(0).volume // returns 1
    $(this).get(0).volume = 0 // returns 0 in the browser but 1 on iOS
});
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

On the other hand I also tried to use cordova-plugin-media but it seems not to be working with mp4 files. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, volume isn't controllable by Javascript in iOS. The muted attribute should mute the video in iOS 10 though, according to this: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('videoSelector', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) videoElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

this.videoElement.nativeElement.muted = true;
```

}
}

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.